# Add custom data to google traffic api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am trying to create a heat map on google map with traffic flow in the road. I have custom data and would like to render those data on the map. Google have traffic api but it provide its own data. I would like to use my own data. Please provide me some solutions or tips.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own data, there is no benefit in trying to use the traffic layer. Just use the heatmap support as provided by the Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap).